# Put Enum next to Bool, next to float in Unity Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to put an Enum(dropdown) in front of a bool and a float value in my custom inspector.
[Much like this, marked in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itPiC.png)
I can't figure out the right code for it in the Unity Inspector, I've tried some things I've found online but they don't seem to do what I want.

Does anyone know how I can achieve what I put in the (poorly edited) picture?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7751-unity-custom-inspectors-tutorial-getting-started). Then use the [EditorGUILayout.Popup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Popup.html) along with `BeginHorizontal`, `EndHorizontal` and `Toggle`.